# Exposed cord on bike tire - replace?

Tags: tire

[image]

The gash is about 3 inches long. Should I toss the tire or should I keep it?

Comment: That seems to be your back wheel. Are you using your brakes properly? (i.e. braking with the front brake), or are you locking the rear wheel? Beyond keeping your components in good state, it can also save your life... http://sheldonbrown.com/brakturn.html

Comment: You say in a comment that it is less than a 1000 miles but do you have a more accurate count?  Care to share the make/model of the tire as well?  It may be a common lifetime of it or a tire we need to avoid.

Comment: I've only locked up my rear wheel while braking twice. Neither lockup was extended. Both lasted maybe a second or so. What's odd is that the tire was fine a week ago when I was changing tubes. I didn't notice any wear like this when swapping tubes.

Comment: @BPugh its a kenda kaliente l3r pro

Comment: Should have been tossed about 2000 miles ago.

Comment: Those tires aren't really low quality (judging by how they are priced) and I'm surprised to see this kind of wear after such short mileage. I almost wonder if you rode through something that ate away at the rubber.  I had really cheap Kenda tires that came with a hybrid bike that lasted for years and probably at least 5000 km.

Comment: @Kibbee - the bike was unused for 10 years. Could the rubber have deteriorated? And I agree - these tires were top of the line Kendas 10 years ago and still basically are. I'm actually really willing to give Kenda a second shot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely replace it.

At this stage, with the rubber delaminating from the case, it could come apart at any time. It's dangerous to use.

Near the bottom of the picture there are some bare threads. It is at that point the tire should have been replaced and *perhaps* only used in an emergency.

PS I see from the picture that the rim is quite worn. It's not far off needing replacement also.

Comment: thanks for the comments. This is odd. Both the tire and rim have seen less than 1000 miles. I've only had the bike for 6 months, and I've only been seriously riding for the last 2 months. Could it just be a case of cheap rim and cheap tire? I'll do some research on rim wear in the mean time and perhaps open another question. How can you tell the rim is worn? Is it that the brake track looks concave in the picture?

Comment: now that I think of it I was using some old stock Tektro brake pads on my rims ... and these were about 10 years old and VERY hard. Could that have been the cause of the wear? I regularly take my bike on commutes and there's this one down hill section I *have* to ride with the brakes on because not only does it involve going downhill but it also involves fitting between two very narrow posts with only a few inches of clearance for my bike ...

Comment: Yes, the concave area where the pads rub. If you ride in wet or dirty conditions the brakes need to be cleaned frequently, else dirt caught on the pads just rips into the rim.

Answer (score 2):

You must replace it. This tire is shot.
I'm curious as to the brand/model of rims as well as the bike itself.
Also, what surfaces are you riding on/

Comment: These are Kenda Kaliente L3R Pro tires on Easton Vista rims. I ride on roads. Asphalt roads. Pretty well-maintained. Occasionally I ride through gravel and gritty road shoulders. I'm surprised because this wear literally appeared overnight.

Comment: I used Kenda before too and they indeed deteriorated fast. Actually even less than 1000 kilometres. This is a known "feature" of cheap Kenda tires. When the rubber starts to delaminate some sort of chain reaction seem to happen and other parts of the tire delaminate too.  Just replace them with something better and forget for a while.